# Python Function return True/False

Tags: python, function, return, anaconda, leap-year

I am writing a Python code that determines whether a year is a leap year. I think my algorithm is fine, but the result of my code is not as desired.

```
def isLeapYear(n):
if n % 400 == 0:
    print ("The year", n, "is a leap year:")
    return True
if n % 100 == 0:
    print ("The year", n, "is a leap year:")
    return False
if n % 4 == 0:
    print ("The year", n, "is a leap year:")
    return True
else:
    print ("The year", n, "is a leap year:")
    return False
isLeapYear(2000)
```

If the code is run, the results are as follows:

```
runfile('C:/Users/username/Desktop/isLeapYear.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/username/Desktop')
The year 2000 is a leap year
```

The first issue is that I do not understand why the runfile filepath is  showing. Second, I would like my code to output whether or not the statement is True or False. So ideally, I'm looking for:

```
The year 2000 is a leap year: True
```

Comment: Instead of `isLeapYear(2000)` you need something like `theValue = isLeapYear(2000)` and then `print theValue`

Comment: If you're running in pycharm or something, the filepath is always shown. Try running from cmd, shouldn't show there

Comment: Do you want to print a boolean, return a boolean, or do both? It seems to me that your `isLeapYear` function is trying to do too many things. The name of the function implies that all it does is determine whether a given year is a leap year. That means simply returning a boolean. Formatting  
 and printing the result should be delegated to another function/section of code.

Comment: That way when you call the function, display the message from inside the function, but you are not storing anywhere the return value

Comment: You're printing the sentence, you are *not* printing the `True`/`False`…

Comment: you know about `calendar.isleap()` I guess, implementation here https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.2/Lib/calendar.py#L100

Answer (score 3):

I feel like it is worth noting as a potential answer that there is a function for this exact purpose without all the code you used to determine if the year is a leap year:

```
import calendar
print calendar.isleap(1900)
```

And as an alternative to utilizing the `calendar` module, you can write this in a simpler fashion which will return a Bool (True/False):

```
def is_leap_year(year):
    """Determine whether a year is a leap year."""

    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not getting the output you want is that when you say

> "I would like my code to output whether or not the statement is True or `False."

you don't specify how you want that output. Right now, your code is mixing `print` statements with `return` statements. If you change all of your `return` statements to `print` statements, the function will print

```
The year 2000 is a leap year: 
True
```

in your terminal.